# Angular 9 force async pipe nested in ngIf async pipe

Tags: angular

```
<ng-container *ngIf="condition$ | async">
    {{ value$ | async }}
</ng-container>
```

How can I force the view to display latest value when condition$ emits true after false ?

---

Update

condition$ and value$ are both derived from the same formGroup.valueChanges and cannot be instances of BehaviorSubject.

Answer (score 0):

What about combining those two and having one observable and subscription like this.
.ts

```
this.viewObservable$ = combineLatest(
      this.condition$,
      this.value$
    ).pipe(
      map(([condition, value]) => {
        return {
          condition,
          value
        }
      })
    )
```

and in your .html you can do this

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(viewObservable$ | async) as data && data.condition">
  {{ data.value }}
</ng-container>
```

Does this help?

Comment: Hi thanks this helped a lot - it works if I do

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(viewObservable$ | async) as data">
  <ng-container *ngIf"data.condition">
    {{ data.value }}
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

as the syntax in the answer does not compile.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by adding a `shareReplay` on your `value$` observable:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="condition$ | async">
    {{ value$ | async }}
</ng-container>
```

```
value$ = obs$.pipe(
  shareReplay(1)
);
```

Or by using a `BehaviorSubject` or `ReplaySubject`

Comment: Sorry, I should have given more context in the question. It's updated now.

Answer (score 0):

you can do as follow to prevent inner subtraction form unsubscribing

```
<ng-container *ngIf="{val: value$ | async} as source">
  <div *ngIf="condition$ | async">
   {{ source.val }}
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-async-condition?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Ideally I would not resort to additional markup - I have plenty of those pipes in the same file.